# Обработка тегов TagHandler

Tags: android, html

Есть текст:  `"Часть [part_1_11/]1.11[/part] содержит... "` обработать и получить текст: `"Часть 1.11 содержит..."` , где 1.11 ссылка, полученная прибавлением `part_1_11` к пути к html файлу, который лежит в assets.    
 Копался в этом вопросе и понял, что для этого используют `Html.fromHtml(String sourse, int flags, ImageGetter imageGetter, TagHandler tagHandler)` , первый аргумент как я понимаю это мой текст, второй аргумент мне не ясен, третий не ясен, но знаю что можно передать null, и четвертый это обработчик тегов, который как я понял мне придется реализовать.

```
public class MyTagHander implements Html.TagHandler{

    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean b, String s, Editable editable, XMLReader xmlReader) {

    }
}
```

Но я не могу понять, как обработать текст. И не уверен, что TagHandler нужен для добавления своих тегов, скорее для подготовки html к обработке стандартными средствами. В общем я запутался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так?

```
String Str = new String("Часть [part_1_11/]1.11[/part] содержит... ");

String[] arr = Str.split("\\[|\\]|\\/");

System.out.println(arr[0] +
    "<a href=" + "file:///android_asset/" + arr[1] + ".html>" + arr[3] + "</a>" +
    arr[6]);
```

[На выходе](https://ideone.com/gUwqtZ)

```
Часть <a href=file:///android_asset/part_1_11.html>1.11</a> содержит...
```

Comment: Я надеялся, что можно обработчик тегов научиться читать такой тег [part_1_11/]1.11[/part] . Если предложенным вами путем, то появляются проблемы. Например тегов в тексте может быть несколько. Ладно, с этим я управился, проверяю длину массива, понимаю сколько тегов. Но еще одна проблема, когда в тексте встречается км/ч , разделение идет по этому сплешу.  Писать регулярку, чтобы не обрабатывались сплеши вне квадратных скобок наверно сложно. Поэтому не могли бы вы написать регулярку, которая  разделит всё без учета сплеша, т.е. я получу part_1_11/

Comment: а там уже сам обработаю, т.к. слово part не сходится с именованием в html файлов, всё равно мне его менять.

Comment: я попробовал так \\[|\\]|   думал всё логично, но результат меня удивил)

Comment: А всё, я понял что надо еще и | удалить, которое является логическим ИЛИ.  Жаль конечно что нельзя научить читать кастомные теги и если много тегов  приходится работать с массивами разной длины.

Comment: @Turalllb: вообще если строки всегда разные лучше найти вариант получше, нежели в моем ответе.

Comment: строки разные, но я должен эту строку получить, и в зависимости какая это строка, подменить её своей. Так что это то что нужно .